# The sequence of self-contained numbers

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence, integer

Let's define a *self-contained number* as a positive integer, whose digits appear in runs of length equal to themselves only. In other words, any decimal digit **d** (excluding **0**) occurs only in runs of length exactly **d**.

## Task

You can choose any of the three methods listed below:

- Given an integer **n**, output the **n**th (either 0 or 1-indexed) self-contained number.
- Given an integer **n**, output the first **n** self-contained numbers.
- Print the sequence indefinitely.

## Examples

- **133322** is a self-contained number because **3** appears in a run of three **3**'s, **1** is single and **2** occurs in a run of two **2**'s.
- On the other hand, **35553355** isn't, because, although **5** and **3** occur five and three  times respectively, they do not form runs of adjacent digits.
- **44422** is not self-contained, because **4** only occurs three times.
- **12222333** isn’t either, because **2** appears in a run of four **2**'s, and it cannot be treated as two separate runs of two **2**'s.

Not surprisingly, this is [OEIS A140057](https://oeis.org/A140057), and its first few terms are:

```
1, 22, 122, 221, 333, 1221, 1333, 3331, 4444, 13331, 14444, 22122, 22333, 33322, 44441, 55555, 122122, 122333, 133322, 144441, 155555
```

---

You can take input and provide output through any of [the standard methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods), in any [programming language](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2028/what-are-programming-languages), while noting that [these loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden by default. This is code golf, so the shortest code in bytes (in every language) wins.

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>104</s> <s>94</s> 83 bytes

-10 bytes thanks to Mr. Xcoder
-11 bytes thanks to Jonathan Allan

```python
i=0
while 1:
 if`i`==''.join(d*int(d)for c,d in zip(`-i`,`i`)if d!=c):print i
 i+=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcxLCoAgFAXQuat4jdR@VEPh7UXIpBuhIkLU5s354aS3nDFstYIX8Zy4D1qNIHgLyyzlfEUE5XqEopz2MdM@OkKgD0nZCXZsUMOT63jXJuUGCS0YeK31Bw)

Comment: ...actually is this acceptable, since [it will fall over once `i` becomes a long](https://tio.run/##DcxLCoAgFAXQeat4jfz0gQoaCG8vQibeCJUIojZvzg8nv3dIcS4FPGu9Ls0TcO4E0xC8hWUWYjwSonQa8ZZO@XTR1jtCpA9Z2gG2r1DBk2t5UyZfFRJq0PFUyg8)? It may be necessary to [use `str`](https://tio.run/##DcpNCoAgEAbQfaeYVmp/VMtiTpNJX4SKI0Rd3lo@ePHJR/BzKeCxug9cO01LRWh5WoUlJw3z0yk1nAFe2wY@a2tcSLR1luDpRdSqV610YuDI1rwZZlli@iuhlA8) (I'm never really sure of these things though).

Comment: @JonathanAllan it's an interesting question. Normally we are allowed to assume that it's within the standard _integer_ type, not _long_, but Python doesn't make this distinction very clear...

Answer (score 6):

## Mathematica, 66 bytes

Prints the sequence indefinitely

```
Do[##&&Print@t&@@(#==Tr[1^{##}]&@@@Split@IntegerDigits@t),{t,∞}]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/98lP1pZWU0toCgzr8ShRM3BQUPZ1jakKNowrlpZuTYWKOAQXJCTWeLgmVeSmp5a5JKZnllS7FCiqVNdovOoY15t7P//AA)

In TIO you have to terminate the execution in order to see the result but in Mathematica works fine.

-12 bytes from Martin Ender

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>76</s> <s>71</s> 68 bytes

Returns the *n-th* term of the sequence, 0-indexed.

```js
f=(n,k)=>+(k+'').replace(/(.)\1*/g,s=>s.length^s[0])||n--?f(n,-~k):k
```

*NB*: As always with recursive functions, the input range depends on Tail Call Optimization support and the stack size of your engine.

#### Demo

```js
f=(n,k)=>+(k+'').replace(/(.)\1*/g,s=>s.length^s[0])||n--?f(n,-~k):k

for(n = 0; n <= 10; n++) {
  console.log('a(' + n + ') = ' + f(n))
}
```

---

## Alt. version, 65 bytes

Takes no input and prints the results with `alert()`, one at a time.

```js
f=k=>f(-~k,+(k+'').replace(/(.)\1*/g,s=>s.length^s[0])||alert(k))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcZBDoMgEADAe1/hzd2qaM8NfsS2CcGFtmzAsKQn069j4pzma35GbP5sZYhppVqdDnp2MPxD30Ho2hZVpo2NJRhB4eN2HX0vehbFFH15v2SZnrjvhikXCIj1XKMbm6IkJsXJ3y8OsB4) (Stops as soon as the maximum stack size is exceeded.)

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 9 bytes

Returns the nth term of the sequence, 1-indexed.

```
µNÔNγ€gJQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//0Fa/w1P8zm1@1LQm3Svw/39DIwA)

**Explanation**

```
µ           # loop over increasing N until counter equals input
 NÔ         # push N with consecutive equal elements deduplicated
   Nγ       # push N grouped into runs of consecutive equal elements
     €g     # get the length of each run
       J    # join to a number
        Q   # check for equality
            # if true, implicitly increment counter
```

Comment: A possible source of inspiration from my 10-byte approach: [`µNγD€gs€ÙQ`](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//0Fa/c5tdHjWtSS8GEodnBv7/bw4A)

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
DŒrZEµ#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/l6KSiKNdDW5X//zc0AAA)

-4 bytes thanks to [Mr. Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59487/mr-xcoder)'s early suggestion.
-1 thanks to [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan).

Takes input from STDIN.

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 70 bytes

```hs
import Data.List
filter(all(\s->read[s!!0]==length s).group.show)[1..]
```

Comment: You can drop the leading `x=` as per our [golfing rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11935/56433).

Answer (score 2):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 20 bytes

```
1{_Abe`::=:*{_p}&)}h
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/37A63jEpNcHKytZKqzq@oFZNszbj/38A)

Explanation:

```
1                       push 1
 {                }h    while TOS is truthy (i.e. forever):            example iteration: 14444
  _                       duplicate                                                       14444 14444       
   Ab                     convert to base 10 (get decimal digits)                         14444 [1 4 4 4 4]
     e`                   run-length encode (array of two-element arrays)                 14444 [[1 1] [4 4]]
       :                  map over the array:
        :                   fold between the two array elements with:
         =                    equality                                                    14444 [1 1]
          :               fold between the array elements with:
           *                multiplication (a.k.a. logical AND for 1 or 0)                14444 1
            {  }&         if this yields a result of 1:
             _              duplicate the number and                                      14444 14444
              p             print it                                                      14444 (output 14444)
                 )        increment the number                                            14445
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 10 bytes

```
≜ℕẹḅ⟨l=h⟩ᵐ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATMAzP9icmFjaHlsb2cy/37ihrDigoHhuoniiqX/4omc4oSV4bq54biF4p@obD1o4p@p4bWQ//8)

Infinitely [generates](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10753/85334) elements of the sequence through its input variable. (If it actually has to do the printing itself, append `&ẉ⊥`.) This is essentially code to solve the corresponding [decision-problem](/questions/tagged/decision-problem) with a `≜` prepended to brute-force the smallest solutions first:

```
        ᵐ    For every
  ḅ          run of
 ẹ           digits in
             the input variable
ℕ            (which is a non-negative integer),
   ⟨l  ⟩     its length
   ⟨  h⟩     and its first element
   ⟨ = ⟩     are equal.
```

I expected this to only take 9 bytes, but `ḅ` seems to require an explicit `ẹ` to separate the digits of a number into runs.

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
Ç≡∟Öz≈¢αV¢
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=80f01c997af79be0569b&i=&a=1)

This program filters all positive integers with a filter.  The digits are run-length encoded.  For each run, the digit must equal the run length.

Comment: [8 bytes i think](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=87d9f88e081d9900&i=&a=1)

Comment: @Razetime: Excellent!

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript 4, <s>83</s> 80 bytes

```
for(i=0;;)+(++i+'').replace(/(.)\1*/g,function(x,y){return y^x.length})||alert(i)
```

```js
for(i=0;i<1000;)+(++i+'').replace(/(.)\1*/g,function(x,y){return y^x.length})||alert(i)
```

Comment: "Javascript 1"? Is there such a language name?

Comment: I mean it works since JavaScript appear, not sure if the name is correwct

Comment: sorry it seems not work in js1. I read and found no replace

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 49 bytes

```
{(grep /^((\d)$0*:<?{$/.comb==$0}>)+$/,^Inf)[$_]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/WiO9KLVAQT9OQyMmRVPFQMvKxr5aRV8vOT83ydZWxaDWTlNbRV8nzjMvTTNaJT629r@1QnFipUJuYgHQAB2FOFPr/wA)

Returns the `n`-th element of the sequence, zero-indexed.

Comment: The `\d` can just be `.`

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 56 bytes

```r
function(n)all((r=rle(el(strsplit(c(n,''),''))))$l==r$v)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYlBCsMwDATvfUYIRAIdapkc/Zg0talBdYzsFvJ6RxkYBnZ1SH7ppidM39g/x7tN@EhhpF/Zez4KFNxEADSoRIgCrWurkjvsUGhZ8NaYJQSd/zjaVquc9j7JOfJ@9atBjpjJmcz36i3MVqSE4wI)

Makes use of run length encoding on the split number.  Returns true if all the lengths equal the values.

Note: I have loaded the `methods` library in TIO to get `el` to work.

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 10 bytes

```
fȯΛ§=L←gdN
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASAA3/9odXNr/@KGkeKCgf9myK/Om8KnPUzihpBnZE7///8xMg)

Returns an infinite list. `↑` is used to show first n elements since it times out.

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 12

```
.f.AqMr8jZ10
```

[Test online!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.f.AqMr8jZ10&input=9&debug=0)

Comment: 10 bytes: `.fqFCr8jZT`

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 48 bytes

```perl
++$\=~s|(.)\1*|$1-length$&&&redo|gre for 1..$_}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19bWyXGtq64RkNPM8ZQq0bFUDcnNS@9JENFTU2tKDUlvya9KFUhLb9IwVBPTyW@tvr/f0ODf/kFJZn5ecX/dX1N9QwMDf7rFgAA)

Returns the n-th element, 1 indexed.

Answer (score 0):

## Java 10, 121 bytes

A lambda from `int` to `int`. The function takes an index *n* and returns the *n*th (1-indexed) sequence value.

```java
n->{int x=0,m=1;for(;n>0;n-=m,m=1)for(var p:(++x+"").split("(?<=(.))(?!\\1)"))m=p.length()==p.charAt(0)-48?m:0;return x;}
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##ZY/NasMwEITP9lOoPq1ILGzooURxQikUCi09pLemB8WRHbn6MdI6pIQ8uyuTHAo97fDN7LLTiaPIu/332A87rWpSaxECeRPKknOa3GBAgXEcndoTEy3YoFe2/fwiwreBTsmki4fYgEqzZrA1KmfZi8Xnm15GLVvpV6Qh1Wjz1VlZJKeqmJuq5I3zwO2q4DavzEToRI7Ck34Bs9lplmWUhV4rhAzWywoYpbC@225LmlFqqp5paVs8AK2irg/CPyIUNL9/WJtFwb3EwVty4pcxSXgan938BJSGuQFZH5ugthDpnw4BvRRmarC5Ki9sK6Gck7KgUzRhRvQf7n3XQXMDtdNa1gj/rjxdDecDQ/eqAgKdVihPk0t6GX8B)

### Ungolfed

```java
n -> {
    int x = 0, m = 1;
    for (; n > 0; n -= m, m = 1)
        for (var p : (++x + "").split("(?<=(.))(?!\\1)"))
            m = p.length() == p.charAt(0) - 48 ? m : 0;
    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 15 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Returns the `n`th term, 1-indexed.

```
Èì òÎeÈÎ¶XÊÃ}iU
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=yOwg8s5lyM62WMrDfWlV&input=OA)

```
Èì òÎeÈÎ¶XÊÃ}iU     :Implicit input of integer U
È                   :Function taking an integer X as argument
 ì                  :  To digit array
   ò                :  Partition between elements where
    Î               :    The sign of their difference is truthy (not 0)
     e              :  All true
      È             :  When passed through the following function as X
       Î            :    First element
        ¶           :    Is equal to
         XÊ         :    Length of X
           Ã        :  End function
            }       :End function
             iU     :Get the Uth integer that returns true
```